# Is it possible to update multiple calendars using google calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I want to allow users of my site to schedule an appointment with other users. Once both users agree on the date and time it will update both their calendars to show this (assuming they are authenticated).

Is this possible or is the Calendar api simply for updating one calendar as an authorized user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user / users you are updating calendars for have both authenticated your application yes you can add events to their calendars.

A few things to note I the beginning.  There is a difference between a [calendar list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) and a calendar.  Calendar list is the list on the left hand side of all of the [calendars](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars) a user has.   A user can have more then one calendar so be sure to ask the users which calendar they will want to add the [event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) to.