# Managing multiple editable google calendars from one web page. How to?

Tags: google-calendar-api

One web page. Firebase backend, vue.js front end.

A sidebar with 100 apartment numbers.

100 apartments, 100 personal calendars, 1 public calendar.

These calendars have no relation to anyones private Google accounts. These are all setup by apartment number. Managed by the buildings manager. They have all the login and password info.

Sample gmail account names which link to calendars:

myapartmetncomplex123-personal@gmail.com

myapartmetncomplex123-public@gmail.com

Example:

Garbage collection moved to 5 PM. That goes on everyone's calendar.  (Public)

Apartment #234:  You have a plumber coming at 2:30PM. (Personal)

Google has "google business", but wondering if I could set this up using standard google tools, swapping cookies, or something similar. Have been playing with that scenario.

Thanks for input!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is possible as long as it is public or authorized user is accessing the calendar. You can check the [Overview of the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/):

> Each user is associated with a primary calendar and a number of other calendars that they can also access. Users can create events and invite other users, as shown in the following diagram:
>   [image]

Related references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28737137/5995040
- [DISPLAY THE CONTENTS OF A GOOGLE CALENDAR WITH PHP](https://spunmonkey.com/display-contents-google-calendar-php/)

Comment: Thanks, yes have dug into the Google API. Seems doable.